# Spreading values across lists in bins

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have data structured into a nested list `my_lst`, example output of its loop:

```
['A', 2312]
['B', 2000]
['C', 1312]
etc...
```

element 1 of each list = `download_budget`

I have a value `download_total = 5000`

I am attempting to append 2 value per list by spreading the download_target value across the different lists based on the following rules:

- The maximum value for element 2 2047
- Element 3 increments by 1 every time element 2 goes beyond 2047

An example using:

```
my_lst = [['A', 2312],
          ['B', 2000],
          ['C', 1312],
          ['D', 3000]]
```

with `download_total` as `5000` should yield the output of

```
['A', 2312, 0, 0]
['B', 2000, 265, 1]     # total d/l = 2312
['C', 1312, 218, 2]     # total d/l = 2312 + 2000 = 4312
['D', 3000, 906, 2]     # total d/l = 5000

#   i.e. (2 * 2047) + 906
```

The first entry will always be a given offset `(e.g. 0, 0)`.
The 2nd entry reads the `download_budget` of the first entry (2312) and attempts to spread the values according to the rules described, making sure the `download_total` is not exceeded.

My attempt:

```
el2 = 0
el3 = 0


for i, element in enumerate(my_lst):
    if i == 0:
        element.append(el2)
        element.append(el3)
    if i >= 1:
        download_budget = my_lst[i-1][1]
        while (download_budget > 2047):
            el3 += 1
            download_budget = download_budget - 2047
            if download_budget < 2047:
                el2 = download_budget
        element.append(el2)
        element.append(el3)
```

Basically, I kind of get the grasp of how I can do this but would be useful to know if there are better ways of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is on the right track but doesn't quite work in that you don't accumulate the download budget as you traverse through the list and are overlooking the end case. And as a result of not accumulating the `download_budget`, you while loop is only met for the second row (`i == 1`) and so nothing else works as it should.

---

As well as fixing these problems, you could simplify it by using modulo (`%`) to get the third column and integer division / remainder (`//`) to get the last column entries.

So, the code for that would look something like:

```
download_total = 5000
budget = 0
for i, row in enumerate(my_lst):
    if i == 0:
        row += [0, 0]
    else:
        target = min(budget, download_total)
        row += [target % 2047 + my_lst[0][2], target // 2047 + my_lst[0][3]]
    budget += row[1]
```

which gives our expected output of:

```
[['A', 2312, 0,   0],
 ['B', 2000, 265, 1],
 ['C', 1312, 218, 2],
 ['D', 3000, 906, 2]]
```

---

If you are stuck with anything just drop a comment but something that may be slight confusing is the use of the `min()` function. On this line, are goal is to assign a value - `target` - which is our goal for what the number for what this row should be (the third and fourth columns).

So we want this target to be as big as possible: all of our budget. *However,* in the case where are budget exceeds the `download_total` (the last row) we want this row to be the download total rather than are budget which would be larger.

Comment: Great thanks for the help. What if the initial i ==0 row offset is different from (0,0)?

Comment: what do you mean by "is different to `[0, 0]`"? just replace the line `row += [0, 0]` with what you want to start with :) please accept as well!

Comment: I changed the initial row values but the other rows do not react to this change in offset. E.g. `row+=[10,2]`..... the end row stays as `['B',2000, 265, 1]`... it should change to `['B', 2000, 275, 3]`

Comment: @arsenal88 Why should it change to that? The other rows don't depend on the downloads of the previous rows, they only depend on the sum of the budgets of the previous rows - at least that is how your example in the question works. Please explain why it should change to that

Comment: So the initial row is important as it is the initial offset by which all others should follow. So an offset of (10, 2) would imply the other others should take this offset into account according to the rules. I didn't stress this initially because I was trying to see how to apply the most simple solution (i.e, with 0,0). Apologies for the lack of clarity!

Comment: How should the others "take this into account" though?

Comment: So if the first entry offset is `row+=[10, 2]`, it means that the following row added would be `[275, 3]`... then the row after would look at this row and this would be the new offset. So 2047 - 275 would be how much more can fit in before 3 increments to 4... plus it all has to be within the budget and download total.. I might be explaining this pretty crap, sorry. It's difficult to articulate.

Comment: `275, 3` is greater than `5000` though! Also only available budget to `'B'` is `2312` so *the only* possible values are `265, 1` regardless of what `'A'`'s downloads are.

Comment: But the difference between `[275, 3]` and `[10, 2]` is not. Which is the main point. `download_total=0` at the point of the first row entry, i.e. `[10,2]`. I hope that clarifies things?

Comment: @arsenal88 See the update, it now works with the offset

Comment: Ah I just made the same change on the code. Yea that's what I was going for :) Cheers for the help. Will accept answer. Have a great day!

Comment: Why the `if`? You can program it linearly by just manipulating the first element of the list `my_lst[0]+=[0,0]` and then write a loop iterating over the list from the second element on `for i, row in enumerate(my_lst[1:]):`